# Angular2 Modal Dialog - how to get access to main modal dialog box

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-material2

**Trying to use a Material Modal Dialog**

(form:https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog)

How to get access to main dialog box, want change background color for diffrent modal type: (alert, info, confirm, etc.. )

> I try use config and option "role", but they have declate type only
>   (alertdialog | dialog)

Comment: please put what you have done so far for this

Comment: I want put some extra CSS class for modal dialog element named "md-dialog-container". This is main modal dialog container which for example I want change background color for diffrent modal type (alert, info, warn, confirm, etc)

Answer (score 0):

From the link which you mentioned you should try this

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(UserProfileComponent, {

   background-color : 'green'

});
```

// to open

```
dialogRef.open();
```

// to close in

```
dialogRef.close();
```

Comment: I don't thing thats posible:

`MdDialogConfig {
    viewContainerRef?: ViewContainerRef;
    role?: DialogRole;
    disableClose?: boolean;
    width?: string;
    height?: string;
    position?: DialogPosition;
}`

Comment: Please put some code or any thing which you have done so that we can help you.